# How to Execute After Effects JSX script using NodeJS in windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, extendscript

I was looking for a sample program to execute Adobe After effects JSX file using NodeJS.

i had look over links which had provided in the forum. but i didnt get it.

it will be appreciated if someone help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this package https://github.com/BenZed/after-effects It has a decent documentation

Comment: Hi, I've tried with that package. It opens after effects application when code runs. My expectation it shouldn't open application and also I've tried command afterfx -noui, even it also open an application and closing it automatically.